# inheriting from a form in C#

Tags: .net, forms, inheritance

I have a couple of already existing forms, let's say CUSTOMERS and ORDERS, and plan to create half a dozen more.  In C# they are partial classes.

```
         public partial class CUSTOMERSFORM : Form
         public partial class ORDERSFORM : Form
```

Now I've decided that it would be good if some generic properties and methods all of these forms will share (not GUI features, but some glue-code for my data middleware) could be inherited.

Can I simply create MyBaseForm with no visual components on it, install these properties and methods in MyBaseForm, and then modify the existing code like this?

```
        public partial class CUSTOMERSFORM : MyBaseForm
        public partial class ORDERSFORM : MyBaseForm
```

If the above is possible, will all of the visual designs I've added to the *existing* Customers and Orders forms remain as they are?  Will anything be broken (assuming there's no method or property naming conflicts)?

EDIT: Does MDI throw any curve-balls here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is supported scenario and how much of the WinForms code base functions.

```
public class MyBaseForm : Form {
  public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public partial class CUSTOMERS : MyBaseForm {
  ...
}

public partial class ORDERS : MyBaseForm { 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple class in your application that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form.

As you said you can then inheriet your current forms from the new class and implement properties. The Visual components of the forms will remain unchanged as these are specified in the designer of the existing forms.

```
public class CustomForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

  //Declaring a protected property will give access ot it for inherieted forms only
  protected object YourProperty
  {
     get;set;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just try to add a Form1:Form to the project, and then create a simple class Class1:Form1 . You can also use Inherited Forms to inherit from forms from other assemblies.